# WiFi Mesh on Windows IoT core

Tags: mesh-networks, arduino, microsoft-windows-iot

I have a project where I need to create a Wi-Fi mesh network of nodes sharing a distributed mesh database that requires relatively quick search access on each node. I was initially thinking of running this using nodes consisting of ESP8266's (https://github.com/Coopdis/easyMesh) each containing an SD card (to store the database), but I'm concerned that most of the Arduino type code I've seen mostly runs in memory. Does this mean I have to load the "database" (In reality probably just a list with 2 or three fields for each record) into memory? I don't want to loop through the list to find the record I'm looking for as I think this will not be efficient. I was hoping to implement some kind of binary search algorithm. Note that entries in this database could go to about 40 000+ entries.

My fallback option is to run Windows IoT Core on a Raspberry Pi where I can use C# and possibly even a real database. My issue with this solution is that I have not been able to find an example of running a mesh network using Windows IoT Core.

Any thoughts or assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any particular reason to use Windows? Linux has good mesh support, a huge selection of databases to pick from and of you really want to program in c# you can use mono

Comment: I just don't have any experience with Linux and I'm a little nervous to learn a new skill on a project of this scale.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I posted this same question to the Microsoft forums and got a reply from IoTGirl saying that WiFi Direct is an option: [Windows IoT Core WiFi Mesh](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fc77339d-25fc-40e2-bf59-31e51361f893/windows-iot-core-wifi-mesh?forum=WindowsIoT)

I need to confirm whether the RPi3B supports WiFi Direct and then also find out if it supports many-to-many via WiFi Direct. (if anyone has any experience on this, feedback would be much appreciated)

Hope this keeps this conversation going or at least helps someone else.